# Assert statement doesn't work properly in bigger or smaller condition

Tags: python, algorithm, assert

I wrote an Algorithm that moves specific elements to specific index of array.

```
arr = [1,0,4,0,True,None,-12,"Jacob"]

def Move(arr,target,index):
    assert index>len(arr) , "index out of array range"
    assert index<0 , "index can't be less than zero"
    _list = []
    for val in arr:
        if val==target:
            _list.append(target)
            arr.pop(arr.index(val))
    [ arr.insert(index,val) for val in _list ]
    return arr
    
Move(arr,0,4)
```

Everything works perfect but I faced a problem in assert statement that shows **(index>len(arr))** condition doesn't work properly in any index.

```
Error:>
        assert index>len(arr) , "index out of array range"
    AssertionError: index out of array range
```

**Every time I get this when logically I shouldn't get this at sub-zero indexes**

**What's wrong with that?**

Comment: You must negate the conditions. `assert` raises an exception if the condition is **false**.

Comment: You can do either `if index>len(arr): raise IndexError("index out of array range")` or `assert(index <= len(arr)), "index out of array range"`. You mixed a bit of the two :)

Comment: Are you maybe looking to do `assert 0 <= index < len(arr)`?

Comment: Thanks for Michael Butscher. I figured it out.

Comment: The basic idea is that you assert the expected condition, and it reports an error if that condition isn't satisfied.

Comment: Assertions can be disabled at runtime. They are meant to find places where an *assumed* invariant is violated during testing and debugging. If you want to *enforce* a restriction on the argument, you should use an explicit `if` statement and raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: Unrelated, don't use a list comprehension as a (dubious) shortcut for a regular loop. `for val in _list: arr.insert(index, val)` is actually *shorter* and doesn't construct an unnecessary list full of `None`s.

Comment: @Stef I would argue that a `ValueError` would be more appropriate than an `IndexError`. `a.insert` itself has no restriction on the size of the index, and certain out-of-range indices will actually work fine. (Roughly, as long as `abs(index) > len(arr)`, `a.insert` will work as intended, prepending or appending an element as appropriate.)